# How pass 5 parameters to Action.java with displaytag

Tags: java, displaytag

would like to spend more than one parameter using displaytag component. Now I can pass a parameter like the example below.

```
<display:column title="excluir" 
   paramId="retornoCrivo" paramProperty="retornoCrivo" 
   href="excluirRegistro.do" style="text-align: center;"> </display:column>
```

Comment: Which example? Please check your post.

Comment: You forgot to add your example.

Answer (score 0):

Check #attribute part of this [documentation](http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/11/displaytag/tagreference.html).